# I want to dynamically propagate a link preferably with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdo

I have created a site with a profile page mostly using PHP (PDO and MySQL db) and ajax calls to update info when entered into the fields. SOme javascript is used for validation.

I now want to do the same with a profile link for several sites but is failing miserably.

I tried concatenation but requiring it to be wrapped in an  confused me.

I want to set a base URL of another website where one might be a member, then allow a user to use an input to insert their username for that website in question.

```
var a = '<a href="https:someotersite.com/'
var b = 'username_abc'
var c = '>Click here for my profile on someothersite</a>
```

I now want to build a link using this info above so that when someone clicks on it, they will open someotersite.com/username_abc on the actual profile page as provided by the user that set the info.

I have some php code that works but require a page load after updating the info...

```
<script>
function visitsomeothersite(){
var someothersite = "<?php Print($someothersite); ?>";
window.open('https://someothersite.com/<?php echo
$_SESSION['someothersite'];?>',
'_blank'
);
}
</script>
```

If there is a fix for this in php using PDO I would appreciate it if the solution also incorporates the ajax so that there is no page load.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: dont get confused with JS (client side scripting) and PHP which is server side. I would suggest to create url in javascript rather then in PHP. like i mentioned in my answer below.

Comment: I am well aware of the difference between the js client side and PHP server-side processing. It is for that reason exactly why I am struggling to get the link. I'm now considering to rather form the completed link using PHP and then transferring it over to the display page. Any suggestions on doing it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In continuation to my comment above Pass parameters in url in javascript rather then in php

```
<script>
    function visitsomeothersite(){
    var someothersite = "<?php Print($someothersite); ?>";
    window.open('https://someothersite.com/+document.getElementById("id of input fielt").value<?php echo
    $_SESSION['someothersite'];?>',
    '_blank'
    );
    }
```

**call above function on any event.**

Comment: Hello @amit wadhwani; Thanks for the quick reply. I probably should have mentioned that however displayed on the same page as where this link is displayed it is in fact only showed if the user has selected it to be displayed by means of a tick box. Hence the code is processed on a different page altogether in PHP and then included using the include_once function.